# How does Mac OSX determine which dylib to load?

Tags: macos, apache, macports, osx-yosemite, dylib

I'm trying to run Apache in Mac OSX Yosemite using MacPorts' PHP (mod_php53.so). Note that I'm not using MacPorts' Apache but Yosemite's Apache with MacPorts' PHP. This was working fine with OSX Mavericks and Mountain Lion in the past.

I get this error when running /usr/sbin/apachectl -t in Yosemite:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 228 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php53.so into server: dlopen(/opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php53.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib\n Referenced from: /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php53.so\n Reason: Incompatible library version: mod_php53.so requires version 6.0.0 or later, but libaprutil-1.0.dylib provides version 4.0.0

In fact, /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib current version is 6.4.0, so it should work.

```
 otool -L /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
 /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib:
 /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.4.0)
```

I guess that Apache is loading the system's libaprutil-1.0.dylib located in /usr/lib:

```
otool -L /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib 
/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib:
/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
```

This is confusing because the error message clearly states that MacPorts' libaprutil was not load because of version incompatibility but I guess it is trying to use the system's libaprutil and don't know how to force Apache to load MacPorts' libaprutil.

I already tried to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the environment contains `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib`. Unset that and it should work.

Libraries are referenced using absolute paths on OS X. You correctly noticed `/opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php53.so` references `/opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib` using its absolute path. However, in the presence of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` the loader ignores the directory components and searches for the filename in the directories specified in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The error message you see is misleading: It is trying to tell you that an error occurred in the code that attempted to handle the `/opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib` load command (which was diverted due to the env variable).

Also, note that since MacPorts builds its PHP against MacPorts Apache, your PHP module is not necessarily binary-compatible to the system Apache. It might work for you, but that's only a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks. DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set in my environment. In any case, I already tested to unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. I also tried by setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with /opt/local/lib/ on front. Macports' php module has been working with Macosx's apache in Leopard, Snow Leopard, Lion, Mountain Lion and Mavericks. I believe this new version should also work. The problem is how to  make sure that in my setup "/opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib" will be used.

Comment: I checked again and apparently /usr/sbin/httpd already loads "/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib". So I guess it is not possible to load again the same library from a different path and mod_php53 is forced to use the library which is already loaded in memory. Is it possible to force httpd to use a different version of the libraries?

Comment: Yeah, if it already loaded `libaprutil-1.0.dylib` from `/usr/lib` that could also explain the problem. Note that while your environment might not have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, apache might add it to its environment during startup (I think that's unlikely, though). You can try forcing MacPorts' libaprutil by setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` for Apache, but that might not be compatible. At this point, you're probably best off either building mod_php against libaprutil in `/usr/lib` or using MacPorts Apache.