# Why doesn't Apache start with newly installed PHP7?

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-sierra

macOS Sierra comes with PHP 5.6 and I wanted to upgrade it to the latest stable version of PHP (7.1.4) by building from the source. What I did was actually a fresh install. First, I removed the old PHP from my system and then download the source code from the php.net and built it. Things work fine except for Apache.

By the way, before I built the PHP, I had to install `apr` and `apr-util packages`. The PHP 7 didn't just accept the same packages under the `/usr/lib` which come with OS by default.

When I execute configtest, I receive this error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 175 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10):
>   Library not loaded: /usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
>   Reason: Incompatible library version:
>   libphp7.so requires version 6.0.0 or later, but libaprutil-1.0.dylib provides version 4.0.0

For some reason, libaprutil-1.0.dylib is not loaded into my environment under `/usr/local/apr/lib/` and that's why I cannot start Apache.

I saw similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490426/how-does-mac-osx-determine-which-dylib-to-load/27501746#27501746) and tried to do the accepted solution. However, I still couldn't manage to start it.

Any ideas why it cannot load `libaprutil`?

Comment: You're probably still trying to load PHP5, go edit the config file and remove reference to the php5 module.

Comment: I removed it. It is commented.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on macOS HighSierra:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 174 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into
>   server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so, 10):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/opt/apr-util/libexec/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib\n  Referenced
>   from: /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so\n  Reason:
>   Incompatible library version: libphp7.so requires version 7.0.0 or
>   later, but libaprutil-1.0.dylib provides version 4.0.0

The reason was in incompatibility between system Apache and brew's php. I believe this shouldn't have happened but I didn't go any deeper. I have disabled the default apache and installed the one from *brew* repository using this instruction: https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
brew install httpd
sudo brew services start httpd
```

This operation required to merge my old config `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` with the new one: `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`
To enable *php* I put in the /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf these lines:

```
 LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
 <IfModule php7_module>
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
     AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

     <IfModule dir_module>
         DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
     </IfModule> 
 </IfModule>
```

It solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure is php work correctly.
Write it in command line:

```
    $php -r 'echo "i am fine" . "\r\n";'
```

In my case, after this command php showed me that he have lost important dependency.

Comment: Please share more details. `$php` sounds strange. Also, if Apache throws such an error, why not fix that instead?

Comment: "he have lost important dependency" - what does that mean? How does this resolve the given problem?